# Getting a data attribute after dynamic change

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr

I have a simple setup with an attribute 'data-id' attached to the element:

```
<div class='row' data-id='1'>
```

If I call `alert($(.row).data(id));` I will get my id 1. 
Next thing I change this id manually or via another script to, say, 2:

```
<div class='row' data-id='2'>
```

and now if I call `alert($(.row).data(id));` I still will get 1 instead of 2.

However, if I change method `.data()` to `attr('data-id')` the result gonna be 2.

What is the reason of such behavior?

Comment: using `.data()` to store data is stored in different location than using `.attr()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason is because jQuery stores all `data` attribute key/value pairs in an object, separate from the DOM. The `data()` method reads from this object.

When you update the `data` attribute using `attr()` you update the DOM *only*, hence the `data()` method reads the old value from the in memory object.

For this reason it's always best to use `data()` as both the setter and getter.

Comment: Can you, please, show any example of how to to use data() as both the setter and getter?

Comment: @bewell late response, but there's example in the [jQuery documentation for `data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

Answer (score 3):

```
$(.row).data('id', 'your new value')
```

Use above setter method to update your `data-id` value

After when you get `$('.row').data('id')` then you get your updated value

Comment: prefere id HTML attribute instead of class

Answer (score 1):

For Set and Get attribute use `data()` instead of `attr()`

```
<div class='row' data-id='1'>
```

```
//set attr
$(.row).data("id","NEW_VAL");

//get attr
$(.row).data("id");
```